# How to host a application made in Python plus Java

Tags: java, python, web, hosting

I have a application built in python and java with front end html. In this there is a file upload field available where the user has to upload the text document. That document gets uploaded, processed using Java and python.

So my query is where we can host this application which has java and python dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best way is to deploy your application in the cloud in that way you have the control to install any software that you want for example python, jdk, tomcat, you can test the options more economic are:

- Heroku: https://www.heroku.com/ 
  -Digital Ocean:  https://www.digitalocean.com/‎

Or you can get an account in [AWS](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Fregistration-confirmation#/start)  to create a virtual machine but be careful with the 12 months free plan

Answer (score 1):

You ca use Google App Engine for deploying the application in the cloud.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/